# CycleGAN cycle loss

Tags: neural-networks, convergence, tensorflow, gan

I was reading the paper of CycleGAN and I was trying to implement it.

However, my models does not converge to any good solution whatsoever, and since I've checked the implementation many times, I think that the problem is on how I understood the algorithm.

Specifically, I have some doubts on how the "cycle" is trained.

At the moment, the gradient wrt one generator (let's say real to segmented), is composed $$L_{disc}^{segm} + L_{rec}^{real \; to \; segm} + + L_{rec}^{segm \; to \; real}$$

However, I'm not too sure about the middle part. In particular, we use the second generator to ensure that the generation is not too far from the initial one, however the gradient wrt the loss, of the other direction, should not influence this right?

Example:
$G_1$ = real to segmented
$G_2$ = segmented to real
If we want to compute the loss wrt $G_1$, we should care only of the reconstruction of it's input to the real domain, right?

However, as explained in the paper (formula with the 3 loss), seems that also the second generator that is used to go back to the original domain is optimized to that that reconstruction is better.

However, this lead to the fact that a generator has to become better at both:

- generating images from one  domain to the other
- reconstruct the other generator output to the initial image

I think this might be the problem that is causing my GAN not to converge, do you agree?

Comment: You could try it both ways and see but I believe the way cycle GAN is trained does involve getting a gradient and updating the weights for both generators in each cycle loss as you stated above.

Comment: @Frobot thank you for the comment, I've actually tried both, but none work, I think it's because the "style switch" is very far (from segmented to real and reverse), and the model is too small to do so (10mil, where the suggested one has 54mil)... i get result as good as an autoencoder with paired data would give, so I think that I'll have to increase the model size, however I have not enough GPU to train 54mil parameters ahah

Comment: Cycle GAN is mostly good for texture type changes (horse to zebra, apple to orange, summer to winter, etc) but not as good with big changes to the shape of an object. So also keep that in mind

Comment: @Frobot yes, I completely agree.. however, the fact that i had the dataset already ready to use and that in their paper they also posted that one, brought me to use that... btw, thank you so much for the time you are taking to answer my questions